# Show field operator is in interaction picture

Tags: homework-and-exercises, quantum-field-theory, interactions

I am reading [these lecture notes](https://www.hep.manchester.ac.uk/u/forshaw/NorthWest/QFT.pdf). In exercise 5.3 on page 7 I have to show that
$$\phi(\vec{x},t)=\int\frac{d^3k}{(2\pi)^3\sqrt{2E_k}}\left(a(k)e^{-ik\cdot x}+a^\dagger(k)e^{ik\cdot x}\right)$$
is in the interaction picture.

My idea to show this would be to show that $\phi(\vec{x},t)=e^{i H_0 (t-t_0)}\phi_S(\vec{x})e^{-iH_0(t-t_0)}$, where $t_0$ is an arbitrary time, $H_0$ is the non-interacting part of the Hamiltonian and $\phi_S$ is the operator in the Schrödinger picture. Is this the right way to go? I did not manage to show the relation?

Comment: Please note that [homework-like questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/714/168783) and [check-my-work questions](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6093/168783) are generally considered off-topic here. We intend our questions to be potentially useful to a broader set of users than just the one asking, and prefer *conceptual* questions over those just asking for a specific computation.

Comment: I think it's not just a homework problem but a more fundamental question and hence not off topic!

Comment: I don't think it is necessarily off-topic (hence why I didn't down vote), but I think it is borderline off-topic. In the current way the question is formulated, it might appear you just want someone to tell you how to do the computation (you even provided an approach, but don't seem to have tried it out). It would be interesting to highlight what is the specific difficulty you are having and show your work so far.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes your guess is correct. In the  Schroedinger picture
\begin{equation}
\phi_S(\vec{x}) = \int \frac{d^3p}{(2\pi)^3}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2E_{\vec{p}}}}[(a_{\vec{p}})_{S}\exp(i\vec{p}\cdot\vec{x}) + h.c.]
\end{equation}

You essentially need to prove
\begin{equation}
a_{\vec{p}}(t) = \exp(-i\omega t)(a_{\vec{p}})_S
\end{equation}

Which you can do from
\begin{equation}
a_{\vec{p}}(t) = \exp(iH_0t)(a_{\vec{p}})_S\exp(-iH_0t)
\end{equation}

Comment: Ok this is how I see it: I have to show $\phi(\vec{x},t)=e^{i H_0 t}\phi_S(\vec{x})e^{-iH_0t} (*)$. For this I need $e^{-i\omega t} a(k)=e^{iH_0 t} a(k) e^{-i H_0 t}$, where $\omega:= k^0$ and $t:=x^0$. My idea to show this would be to show that this is true for an arbitrary state $|k_1,\cdots k_N>$. If $k\neq k_i$ then both sides are zero. If one $k_j=k$ then the LHS of $(*)$ is: $|k_1,..,k_{j-1},k_{j+1},...,k_N>e^{-i\omega t}$ and the RHS is $|k_1,..,k_{j-1},k_{j+1},...,k_N>e^{-i\omega t}$, which is the same as the LHS. Since I have shown it for a general state the relation (*) is true.